How do I add a custom developer icon on the apple app store?
O noticed that some apps have a custom icon displayed above the developer name: enter image description here
Example
I could not find any place in App Store Connect where to set this, is this something only certain developers have access to, or something I am missing?
I own a business account on the App Store, with apps published.
Tried looking in App Store Connect

Be a big enough developer with millions of downloads

Yeah, well do they reach out to you?

I guess so. It's probably related to being featured on the App Store and working directly with the App Store team.  Fruit Ninja has >1 billion downloads
